# How to split a column values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
PK  Name Mobile  questions          
1   Jack 12345   [{'question':"how are you","Response":"Fine"},{"question":"whats your age","Response":"i am 19"}]

2   kim 102345   [{'question':"how are you","Response":"Not Fine"},{"question":"whats your age","Response":"i am 29"}]
3  jame  420
```

I want the output df to be like

```
PK    Name   Mobile Question 1     Response 1  Question 2        Response 2
1     Jack   12345   How are you   Fine        Whats your age    i am 19
2     Kim    102345  How are you   Not Fine    Whats your age    i am 29
3     jame   420
```

Comment: will you always have 2 questions in the list?

Comment: There are 10 questions but it can varie.

Comment: As of now there are 10 questions however there can be entries where the questions is blank or nan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `explode` to first create a row per element in each list. Then create a dataframe from this exploded series and keep indexes. `assign` a column to get incremental value per row per index group, then `set_index` and `unstack` to create the right shape. finally rename the columns and `join` to original df

```
# create a row per element in each list in each row
s = df['questions'].explode()

# create the dataframe and reshape
df_qr = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)\
          .assign(cc=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1)\
          .set_index('cc', append=True).unstack()

#flatten columns names
df_qr.columns = [f'{col[0]} {col[1]}' for col in df_qr.columns]

# join back to df
df_f = df.drop('questions', axis=1).join(df_qr, how='left')

print (df_f)
   PK  Name  Mobile   question 1      question 2 Response 1 Response 2
0   1  Jack   12345  how are you  whats your age       Fine    i am 19
1   2   kim  102345  how are you  whats your age   Not Fine    i am 29
```

Edit, if some rows are emppty strings instead of lis, then create `s` this way:

```
s = df.loc[df['questions'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)), 'questions'].explode()
```

Comment: yes for exaple in the answer you have written the there is no Question1 coming in my output insted i am getting 01 also there os no Response columns i am getting jusst getting column name 01 and value as {'question':"how are you","Response":"Not Fine"}

Comment: i have editied the question  could you please suggest . Thank you for saving me

Comment: it ran succesfully but it removed the blank values i need the values there also if you will see my edited question jame have blank in question  but that is present in output.

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T